# For a small dictionary list program runs, but for a large list it gives an error

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I am new to C and in one assignment I have to load a 141,000 word dictionary in computer memory.

Below code works when loading a smaller dictionary (I tried up to 700 words) but when loading a bigger dictionary compiler gives segmentation error.

On running debugger, I can see call stack does not have next function (main) in queue when loading 140k word dictionary [error on 140k word list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYPFq.png). But for small dictionary with 700 words call stack has the next function (main) in the queue ready for execution [the call stack is ok with small list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4bZO.png)

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    char inword[1]; // to store word
    FILE *infile = fopen(dictionary, "r"); // open file location is in definations of speller.c
    // check if filepointer worked
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open DICTIONARY");
        return false;
    }
    //loop over each word
    while (fscanf(infile, "%s", inword) != EOF)
    {
        node *temp;
        //save word in node
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not malloc");
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(n->word, inword);
        n->next = NULL;
        // hash word to obtain hash value
        int hashn = hash (inword);
        // insert the word into hash table
        if (table[hashn] == NULL)
        {
            n->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            n->next = table[hashn];
        }
        table[hashn] = n;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(infile);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    //  printf("xxThe size of dictionary loaded is : %i\n", count); // for testing
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `char inword[1];` allows you to store exactly one character. You might want to increase that quite a bit. You might also consider `while (fscanf(infile,"%s",inword) == 1)` instead. There's important code missing, like the definition of `node`, so put together a [mcve].

Comment: You can probably greatly simplify the logic to just `n->next = table[hashn];`.

Comment: @code2020:  You can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote those that helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inword[1]` is only big enough to store an empty string.

```
// char inword[1]; // to store word
char inword[100];
```

Use width limits.  Test positively for expected result.

```
// while (fscanf(infile,"%s",inword) != EOF)
while (fscanf(infile,"%99s",inword) == 1)
```

---

I suspect unposted `node` may need re-work too.

Comment: thank you, setting inword array to bigger number is what it needed. program did not break when I used only list of 700 words and code worked. I am trying to understand why  did it work at all when array was too small.  I am assuming somehow fscanf has forced the words into the inword array? thanks for taking time to answer, much appreciated

Comment: @code2020: with a one byte array, you have undefined behavior, which may have no visible effect for small words because of how the local variables happen to be stored on the stack. Your 700 word file might have just small words and your complete dictionary probably has much longer ones.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues. Here is a corrected version:

```
// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary) {
    node *n;
    char inword[sizeof(n->word)]; // <-- use a larger array, assuming n->word is an array
    FILE *infile = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    // check if filepointer worked
    if (infile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open DICTIONARY\n");  // <-- add trailing newline
        return false;
    }
    //loop over each word
    while (fscanf(infile, "%99s", inword) == 1) {  // <-- specify maximum length and test for success
        //node *temp;    // <-- unused variable
        //save word in node
        n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not malloc\n");  // <-- add trailing newline
            fclose(infile);  // <-- close input file
            return false;
        }
        strcpy(n->word, inword);
        // hash word to obtain hash value
        int hashn = hash(inword);
        // insert the word into hash table
        n->next = table[hashn];  // <-- works too if table[hashn] is null
        table[hashn] = n;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(infile);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking time to write above, i did some clean up following your feedback.

Comment: @code2020: now that you have enough reputation to vote, you can upvote those answers that helped you.